# What happens to a ball if it is snatched by a bird?

Tags: cricket

If a ball has been hit and has not yet touched the ground, then gets plucked from the air by a raptor (or a falcon, eagle, etc.) and dropped over the boundary, will that still score a six, or will it be a dead ball?

Answer (score 5):

While the none of the [Laws of Cricket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/all-laws) or any of the [playing conditions for any ICC tournaments](https://www.icc-cricket.com/about/cricket/rules-and-regulations/playing-conditions) cover this *precise* scenario, the playing conditions do cover the case of the ball hitting a camera suspended over the field; quoting from section 20.1.3 of the [One Day International playing conditions as of June 2019](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2018/09/27/c9264750-2778-44df-949f-d1a8dfbdc402/04-Mens-ODI-Playing-Conditions-2018.pdf):

> In a match where cameras are being used on or over the field
>   of play (e.g. Spidercam), should a ball that has been hit by the
>   batsman make contact, while still in play, with the camera, its
>   apparatus or its cable, either umpire shall call and signal ‘dead
>   ball’. The ball shall not count as one of the over and no runs shall
>   be scored.

Given that, I think it would be more than reasonable for an umpire to call dead ball in the scenario you describe.